# What does $C_b$ norm mean

Tags: functional-analysis, definition, normed-spaces, malliavin-calculus

Recently I have been reading a paper where the norm $||f||_{C_b}$ and $||f||_{C_b^m}$ appear without definition. So I would like to know what is the default definition in the mathematics community for these two norm? Thanks!

Comment: Did this show up in the context of Malliavin calculus?

Comment: It showed up in a paper written by Shigeo Kusuoka and Daniel Stroock named "Applications of the Malliavin Calculus"

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\|f\|_{C_{b}(K)}=\sup\{|f(x)|: x\in K\},
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\|f\|_{C_{b}^{m}(K)}=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\|f^{(k)}\|_{C_{b}(K)},
\end{align*}
where $K$ is a compact set, here we assume the context is in one-dimensional, for higher dimensional is defined similarly, using the multi-indices $\alpha=(\alpha_{1},...,\alpha_{n})$ that $|\alpha|=\alpha_{1}+\cdots+\alpha_{n}=k$, $0\leq k\leq m$, and consider $\|\partial^{\alpha}f\|_{C_{b}(K)}$.